# Using form request data in Laravel 5.3 mailable views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Looking around I cant find much information on how to do this. Plenty of the same examples just explaining the basic implementation of the mailable class but thats it.

I am sending an email from a contact form and have a route set up for testing that my form posts to:

```
Route::post('/sendmail', function() {    
    Mail::to("my email.com")->send(new MyTestMail());
});
```

I then have my mailable class which I have passed a test variable as a test string to:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class MyTestMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $test;

    /**
    * Create a new message instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test = "test";
    }

    /**
    * Build the message.
    *
    * @return $this
    */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.myTestMail');
    }
}
```

What I wish to do is have access to my post values from the contact from and use them in the email view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try passing the data you need to the constructor of that mailable.

```
public $postdata;

public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->postdata = $data;
}
```

Now 'postdata' will be available to your view.

```
Mail::to("my email.com")->send(new MyTestMail($request->all()))
```